# C, unable to print properly the data inside the struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm a newbie on C so have a problem, after I insert some data inside the array of the struct I want to print it, like a clients or in this case a list of cars in a store, problem is function is done but no data is showed, I think the function is correct but the parameters are wrong and there's nothing to retrieve

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct coches {
    int id;
    char nombre[10];
    char marca[10];
    char color[10];
    float kilometros;
};

int insertar_datos(struct coches concesionario[30]);
int checkout(char login[10], char password[10]);
void mostrar_datos(struct coches concesionario[30], int x);

int main(void) {
    struct coches concesionario[30];
    int menu, credenciales, x;
    char login[10], password[10];

    puts("\n<><><>Bienvenido<><><>\n");

    puts("\nAntes de poder usar el sistema deber estar autentificado\n");
    while (credenciales != 1) {
        puts("\nDime tu usuario:\n");
        scanf("%10s", &login);
        puts("\nDime tu password:\n");
        scanf("%10s", &password);
        credenciales = checkout(login, password);
    }

    while (menu != 3) {
        puts("\nQue deseas hacer?\n");
        puts("\n1)Insertar datos\n2)Listar coches\n3)Salir del programa\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                insertar_datos(concesionario);
            case 2:
                mostrar_datos(concesionario, x);
        }
    }
}

int checkout(char login[10], char password[10]) {

    if ((strcmp(strlwr(login), "12345") == 0) &&
        (strcmp(strlwr(password), "12345") == 0)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int insertar_datos(struct coches concesionario[30]) {
    char respuesta[3];
    int x = 0;
    system("cls");
    while (!strstr(respuesta, "no")) {
        puts("\nDime la id:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &concesionario[x].id);
        system("cls");
        puts("\nDime el modelo:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%10s", &concesionario[x].nombre);
        system("cls");
        puts("\nDime la marca:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%10s", &concesionario[x].marca);
        system("cls");
        puts("\nDime el color:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%10s", &concesionario[x].color);
        system("cls");
        puts("\nDime los kilometros:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &concesionario[x].kilometros);
        system("cls");
        x++;
        puts("\nQuieres insertar algo mas?\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%3s", &respuesta);
        system("cls");
        strlwr(respuesta);
    }

    return x;
}
```

And here is the problem:

```
void mostrar_datos(struct coches concesionario[30], int x) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < x) {
        printf("\nNombre: %d\n\nApellido: %s\n\nDireccion: %s\n\nEdad: "
               "%d\n\nTelefono: %d\n",
               &concesionario[i].id, &concesionario[i].nombre,
               &concesionario[i].marca, &concesionario[i].color,
               &concesionario[i].kilometros);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dereferencing '&' on argument in printf ( printf(...", &concesionario[i].id)? 

You need that only on scanf(to pass the address).

Comment: You should get rid of the `&` operators in the `printf` call

Comment: You also need to increment `i` in the loop. Why not use a `for` loop instead of `while`?

Comment: You should get a better compiler. Good C compilers, like GCC, will warn that the types of the arguments to `printf` don't match the format specifiers.

Comment: & problem fixed, while: a guy told me its the way to do it :(

Comment: Well the gay was wrong.

Comment: Please try to [minimize your example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, use proper indentation and a consistent style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programing in C: Operation with struck, erase modifier and print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205241/programing-in-c-operation-with-struck-erase-modifier-and-print)

Comment: @Deduplicator doesn't quite look like a duplicate

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Maybe, am not convinced. Still for both his "questions" `debug my unformatted blob for me is not an acceptable question` also applies.

Comment: Questions should come with a minimal example of the problem, not with a copy and paste of your full project.

Answer (score 2):

```
void mostrar_datos(struct coches concesionario[30],int x){

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++){

        printf("\nNombre: %d\n\nApellido: %s\n\nDireccion: %s\n\nEdad: "
           "%s\n\nTelefono: %f\n",
           concesionario[i].id, concesionario[i].nombre, concesionario[i].marca,
           concesionario[i].color, concesionario[i].kilometros);
     }
}
```

a `for` loop fits better to your requirements than a `while` loop. Also note the removed `&` in the printf and the changed `%d` to `%s` for `concesionario[i].color` because it´s a string.

you forgot to assign `x` in the case 1, replace it with:

```
 x = insertar_datos(concesionario);
```

you also should initialize it to `0` if someone choose `2` in the menu before `1`.

Comment: Also, `kilometros` is a `float`, and should use `%f`.

Comment: Thanks, anyway i remplaced the code part and when i call for it dosent work, program return to the while of the switch.

Comment: you call this method with the uninitialized variable `x`, so the chances are good, that `x` is smaller than 1 and so it doesn´t print anything

Comment: Yeah i though that but after i tried to insert several data in the array of the struct problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the difference is between

```
&concesionario[i].id
```

and

```
concesionario[i].id
```

and it should make sense that printf doesn't print anything reasonable. You should investigate the documentation of your compiler to find out how to make it give you warnings for bad code. Most people set up their compilers so that lots of wrong code won't be accepted by the compiler.

Comment: You probably meant "silently accepted", because often warnings (which one can ignore if so inclined) are better than errors.